Volume of 'wedge' of unit ball bounded by three vectors.
Let $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ be the unit sphere, and $v_1, v_2, v_3 \in \mathbb{R}^3$ unit vectors. The three great circles interesecting each pair of $v_i$ split $S$ into eight disjoint regions (four if two of the $v_i$ are antipodal). I am interested in the surface area of the smallest such region (or, rather, the ratio between this area and the area of $S$), and was wondering if there was an expression for this in terms of the $v_i$. Note that this is equal to the volume of the 'wedge' given by the $v_i$ divided by the volume of the unit sphere.
If we instead consider the unit circle, and $v_1,v_2 \in \mathbb{R}^2$, then the area of the small wedge divided by the area of the circle is $\arccos(v_1 \cdot v_2)/(2\pi)$. I suspect an analogous expression holds in higher dimensions as well.

The center of the sphere and the three vectors form a tetrahedron. The spherical segment has the same solid angle as the face away from the center. Then you can use the solid angle formula from wikipedia:
$$\tan \frac12\Omega=\frac{\vec a\cdot(\vec b\times \vec c)}{abc+a(\vec b\cdot \vec c)+b(\vec c\cdot \vec a)+c(\vec a\cdot\vec b)}$$
Once you have the solid angle, the volume is trivial to calculate
$$V=\int dV=\iint r^2drd\Omega=\frac13\Omega$$

Due to antipodal symmetry only 4 cases need be considered.
V is volume of cut  Wedge= portions of adjoining (spherical cap + cone)  and A is area of base spherical triangle.
$$ \frac{V}{\frac43 \pi r^3}=\frac{A}{4\pi r^2}$$
The 4 areas are related to  their spherical excesses
$$ r^2( \alpha+\beta+\gamma-\pi,~\pi-\alpha-\beta+\gamma,~ \pi+\alpha-\beta-\gamma,~\pi-\alpha+\beta-\gamma~)$$
The first area is well known, other three are obtained by cyclically replacing two of three angles by their supplements.
